# Error 500.19 installing Sitecore 9 XP0 on a clean Windows 10 machine

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-framework

While installing Sitecore 9 XP0 on a new Windows 10 VM I came across the following error.

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.
>
> Detailed Error Information: Module       IIS Web Core Notification
>   BeginRequest Handler     Not yet determined Error Code       0x80070021
>   Config Error     This configuration section cannot be used at this
>   path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level.
>   Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set
>   explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy
>   allowOverride="false". Config File
>   \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.sc\web.config Requested URL
>   http://sc90.sc:80/ Physical Path     C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.sc Logon
>   Method       Not yet determined Logon User       Not yet determined
>
> Config Source:    73:         74:         75:
>
> More Information: This error occurs when there is a problem reading
>   the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some
>   cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused
>   this error. View more information »

Answer (score 9):

The error points to a lock on the IIS configuration. However, after some research, I came across to the solution which I share here hoping it will save someone else's time.

The reason for the error is that ASP.NET, one of the prerequisites, was not installed. The interesting thing is that Windows 10 doesn't show the ASP.NET feature on its "Windows Features" window (Turn Windows features on or off) therefore it cannot be enabled as before.

The way to enable ASP.NET in Windows 10 is by executing the following command in a console as Administrator:

*dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45*

When ASP.NET is installed the applicationHost.config (in %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config) gets updated unlocking some configuration sections that are updated by Sitecore's web.config file. And this solves the issue.

Comment: Its worth noting that this fix isn't unique to 9.0, I just used it for a new 8.0 site as well.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error too, I had all the required .NET framework and .NET Core runtimes. Was just missing the Url Rewrite module in IIS.

You can download the appropriate installer for your OS here https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Please visit
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/

also https://www.supportsages.com/how-to-enable-http-redirection-in-iis-servers/
to know step by step procedure on who to enable

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: You can provide more details on how to enable Url Rewrite module