# Local set up of existing Sitecore site, troubleshooting Web.config

Tags: iis

I need to set up an existing Sitecore site on my local machine (version 9.2).

After installing a default Sitecore instance (successfully), the core and master databases were restored using back ups of the existing site's core and master databases and the server files were copied to my local machine. Of course Web.config from the back up is adjusted to point to the domain on my local machine but no other changes are made.

Upon trying to sign into Sitecore, I get an internal server error:

[image]

The "View more information" link takes me to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&IIS70Error=500,19,0x8007000d,19044  which states for the 0x8007000d Error Code:

[image]

I have confirmed that both the Web.config and App_Config/ConnectionStrings.config files are valid XML.

Based on the Microsoft documentation, that only leaves "Check the unidentified XML elements, and then install the relevant IIS modules" as the possible issue.

The challenge is that the Web.config file is over 500 lines long.

**Is the only solution to go line by line in the file, commenting/uncommenting each line (with a server reboot each time) to find the problematic element?**

**What is the general approach to troubleshooting something like this?**

Comment: Did you make entry in the host file?

Comment: @SumitBhatia yes, an entry is created automatically when installing Sitecore. I just double checked that it's there again though.

Comment: ok And did you check that you have all the prerequisites installed on IIS level? Refer this https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8884/error-500-19-installing-sitecore-9-xp0-on-a-clean-windows-10-machine

Comment: @SumitBhatia I know that I have the prerequisites for Sitecore itself by default because I can install Sitecore by itself without any problems. It's when the databases are restored to the back ups and the server files are copied that I get problems.

Comment: I would check if IIS have all required modules installed. I had something similar when i had no Url Rewrite module. Also check App Pool user permission to your website folder.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, the very safest way to move site would be install Sitecore on your new machine and then restore the master and core databases. And you are doing the same as you mentioned in the question.

To simply copy the files over is more complicated. It may be an issue if any required module is missing. And you have to troubleshoot it more to identify what is causing the issue. So you can check the Sitecore error logs and check if you are getting any issues with any module that is not installed? Otherwise, you need to run first with the default web.config and then put the changes into that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any sections specified in the < configSections > area that dont exist in the web.config? Or more importantly any sections (other than appSettings, location, system.webServer, system.web, system.net and runtime) that are not included in < configSections >?

My suggestion would be to remove (or swap for one from vanilla install) each section at a time to see if you get past the config error. That will show you which section it is in. You can then take it from there.